# Counter examples for closed and bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

(1) Given an example of sets $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq\dots$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that each $A_n$ is bounded and
$$\bigcap ^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n= \emptyset.$$

(2) Given an example of sets $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq\dots $ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that each $A_n$ is closed and 
$$\bigcap ^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n= \emptyset.$$ 
[image]

***My attempt:***

For (2) $A_n=[n,\infty)$

(1) $\left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) \right\}^\infty _{n=1}$

Am I correct?

Comment: You have the containment sign backwards in statement  (1).  Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: Your answers do not satisfy $A_k \subseteq A_{k+1}$. The reverse containment is satisfied. Indeed, the stated requirements cannot be satisfied unless $A_1 = \emptyset$, for both problems.

Comment: @Bungo.. you mean that not satisffies increasing property right?

Comment: Correct, your sequences are both decreasing, not increasing. Are you sure the problem statements should not request $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$?

Comment: @Bungo..please can you give me examples

Comment: Well, you can rather trivially set $A_k = \emptyset$ for all $k$, and that will work for both problems, regardless of whether the sequences need to be increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @quasi.. the problem i have written is correct

Comment: So in that case, your answers are wrong, since your containments go the wrong way.

Comment: If the problems are correct as stated, then for both problems, an increasing sequence $A_n$ satisfies the requirements if and only if $A_1 = \emptyset$. So, that's not a very interesting problem...

Comment: @quasi..yea you are right i am thinking to fix it but cant't get answer

Comment: See Bungo's comment. The intersection of an increasing sequence of sets (increasing with respect to inclusion) is always just the first set (i.e., $A_1$).

Comment: @Bungo ..you mean i choose sequence like $(0, 1-\frac{1}{n}] $

Comment: The empty set doesn't have a standard interval notation. Just use the empty set symbol (i.e., let $A_1=\varnothing$).

Comment: Your intersection simplifies to $A_1$ (since, based on your stated containments, $A_1$ must be contained in all the others). So you need to have $A_1=\varnothing$, else it won't work. And once you set $A_1=\varnothing$, just make sure the other sets satisfy the specified requirements.

Comment: @quasi..but how choose sequence $A_1=\phi$ and remaing non empty increasing

Comment: Use intervals, and draw them (at least mentally), to make sure they work. You shouldn't need help on that. Alternatively, as already suggested in the comments, a trivial solution, which works for both problems, is to let _all_ the sets be empty.

Comment: Still, I suspect the intended problem had the containments reversed, and if so, your original answer would be correct. Is the problem from a book? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

Nope this is incorrect. In fact with $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq..... \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\bigcap ^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n=A_1$$ therefore $$A_1=\emptyset.$$